# Cutting a diagram in 4 Parts

Tags: c#, grid, diagram

Hi i would like to split my Diagram in four Parts. How can i define the other 3 Bounds.

```
Rect b = activeDiagram.Panel.DiagramBounds; // b = (-370, -190, 3099, 2450)
Rect bounds1 = new Rect((new System.Windows.Point(b.X,b.Y)), (new System.Windows.Point( (w/2) + b.X, (h/2) + b.Y ))); // bounds1 = (-370, -190, 1549.5, 1225)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering, that you want to get 4 equal rectangles from diagramm bounds and that `w` and `h` in your example are width and height, you can use following code:

```
Rect bounds1 = new Rect(b.X, b.Y, w/2, h/2); //top left corner
Rect bounds2 = new Rect(b.X, b.Y + h/2, w/2, h/2); //bottom left corner
Rect bounds3 = new Rect(b.X + w/2, b.Y, w/2, h/2); //top right corner 
Rect bounds4 = new Rect(b.X + w/2, b.Y h/2, w/2, h/2); //bottom right corner
```